# How to bound the sup norm of a Rademacher process or equivalently a Gaussian process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, pr.probability

I want to know how to find an upper bound of the following expectation taken for both $t$ and $y$ as

$$\mathbb{E}\sup_{x \in D} \left|\sum_{k=1}^n t_k x^T y_k\right|,$$
where $D$ is the set of vectors defined by
$$D = ( x \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid 0\leq x_i \leq 1, \forall 1\leq i\leq m ),$$

$\left(t_k\right)_{k=1}^n$ is the Rademacher sequence, that is, $t_1, \cdots, t_n$ are i.i.d. copies of a random variable $t$ taking values $\pm 1$ with $\mathbb{P}(t=1)=\mathbb{P}(t=-1)=1/2$, and
$(y_k)$ are i.i.d. copies of a random vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ taking values $e_1,\cdots,e_m$ with $\mathbb{P}(y = e_i)=p_i$. Here, $e_i$ denotes the vector from the standard basis with $i$-th component being 1 and the others being 0.

I first get rid of the absolute value as
\begin{align}
& \mathbb{E}\sup_x \left|\sum t_k x^T y_k\right| \leq \mathbb{E}_y\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathbb{E}_s \sup_x\left| \sum s_k x^T y_k\right|\right) \\\\
 \leq  & \sqrt{2\pi} \mathbb{E}_y\left(\mathbb{E}_s \sup_x\left(\sum s_k x^T y_k \right)\right)
= \sqrt{2\pi} \mathbb{E} \sup_x\left(\sum s_k x^T y_k \right),
\end{align}
where $s_k$ are i.i.d copies of a standard normal random variable.

Then, how to continue? My guess is that the upper bound seems to be of order $O(\sqrt{n})$. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: $\varepsilon $?

Comment: where is $\varepsilon$?

Comment: First line. Should be $t$?

Comment: This is a random walk, so yes, it is $O(\sqrt{n})$ and furthermore, in the limit, the distribution will approach a d-dimensional Brownian motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantity is of the order $n$ (at least without any additional restriction on the $p_i$'s).

To see the upper bound:

$$\mathbb{E}\sup_{x \in D} \left|\sum_{k=1}^n t_k x^T y_k\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E} \left| 1^T y_k\right|   \leq n$$

where $1^T$ denotes the $1$'s vector.

To see the lower bound, set $p_i=1/n$.  Now with at least constant probability the $y_k$'s will include at least $.1 n$ distinct vectors. Also, with large probability, at least, say, 40% of the $k$'s with distinct $y_k$ vectors will be such that $t_k = +1$. Let $S$ denote the resulting set of at least $.36 n$ indices / $k$'s. We can then define $x \in D$  such that $x_k =1$ if $k \in S$ and $x_k=0$ otherwise.  When this occurs (which happens with constant / non-zero probability) the expression is $\gg .36 n$.

(It is possible to choose $p_i$'s such that the quantity is significantly smaller. Take $p_1 =1$ and $p_i=0$ (for $i>1$), then the sum is essentially that of $n$ Rademacher functions, and the expectation should be around $\sqrt{n}$).

Answer (score 0):

Is the following correct?

Notice that $t$ and $y$ are independent, we have $\mathbb{E} = \mathbb{E}_y\mathbb{E}_t$. Then we focus on the inner expectation $\mathbb{E}_t$ for some fixed $y_1=e_{(1)},\cdots, y_n=e_{(n)}$.

$$\mathbb{E} \sup_{x\in D}\left|\sum_{k=1}^n t_k x^T y_k\right| =  \mathbb{E} \sup_{x\in D} \left|\sum_{k=1}^n t_kx_{(k)} \right|\leq \mathbb{E}\left|\sum_{k=1}^n t_k \right|\leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}} \quad ???$$

The above upper bound does not depend on $y$. Thus, it is also an upper bound for the expectation of both $y$ and $t$. Is this correct?

Comment: The first inequality is wrong... it seems that it should be of order n.

Answer (score 0):

$t$ is symmetric, but $y$ is not necessarily so.  My intuition is that an upper bound would have to depend on the set of $p_i, i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$, for .  Does that make sense?

Comment: At the beginning, I also think so. However, I did not find a mistake in my answer provided below... So I doubt..

Comment: If you write $\xi(x) = tx^Ty$, you should be able to write down the pmf of $\xi(x)$ given $x$.  In particular, $\mathbb{E}\xi(x) = 0$ and $Var(\xi) \le m$.  You could then say that $f_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_k(x)$ with $\xi_k(x)$ iid; which means that you have a WLLN for $\frac{f_n(x)}{n}$ and also large deviations bounds.  I am thinking that these little pieces should start to give a decent picture towards a bound, since $$\mathbb{E}\sup_{x\in D} |f_n(x)|$ is what you are interested in.

Comment: actually, $Var(\xi(x)) \le 1$.